# Not able to return array data with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm currently trying to simply return an array with codeigniter active record which I have done thousands of times before. I'm pretty sure this will be a simple problem but I just can't seem to find the problem. Need another eye!

The code below is where everything seems to be going wrong, especially within the foreach. When I remove the foreach and just use a simple where clause like so: `$this->db->where( array('posts.category_string' => $category['category_string'], 'published' => 1) );` it displays records in the view like I was expecting.

```
public function get_most_relevant($user){

    $categories = $this->get_users_most_common_categories($user);

    $this->db->order_by('posts.date_created','DESC');
    $this->db->limit(25);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->select('posts.image_name as post_image');
    $this->db->select('posts.random_string as post_string');
    $this->db->select('posts.date_created as post_creation');
    $this->db->join('users', 'posts.user_string = users.random_string','left'); 
    foreach($categories->result_array() as $category){
        $i = 0;
        if($i == 0){
            $this->db->where( array('posts.category_string' => $category['category_string'], 'published' => 1) );
        }else{
            $this->db->or_where( array('posts.category_string' => $category['category_string'], 'published' => 1) );
        }   
        $i++;
    }

    $posts = $this->db->get();

    return $posts;

}
```

I have also used the print_r() function on the function below to make sure that this is returning records which is is

```
public function get_users_most_common_categories($user){

    $this->db->order_by('category_occurence', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit(25);
    $this->db->group_by('category_string');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select('COUNT(category_string) AS category_occurence');
    $this->db->from('views');       
    $this->db->where('user_string', $user);
    $this->db->or_where('ip_address', $user);

    $categories = $this->db->get();

    return $categories;

}
```

Array from get_users_most_common_categories() function:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13
        [post_string] => zmn2GxUNeD1V
        [user_string] => jpgYW9kXqnJ9
        [category_string] => cCU8oEQHYLWP
        [ip_address] => 0.0.0.0
        [date_created] => 2014-02-22 23:56:42
        [category_occurence] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 14
        [post_string] => 9qlnMxRg
        [user_string] => jpgYW9kXqnJ9
        [category_string] => 8RfRDWrG5QB7
        [ip_address] => 0.0.0.0
        [date_created] => 2014-02-22 23:56:44
        [category_occurence] => 1
    )

)
```

Hope something can help, your time is appreciated!

Comment: do you want to set `where` condition multiple times?

Comment: I use the `where` condition for the first loop and then `or_where` condition foreach loop after `$i == 0`

Comment: You're setting `$i = 0;` within the loop, so you're setting the `where` multiple times, not using `or_where`.

Comment: @learn As Dave said, you are initializing $i inside the loop. so move that line above foreach.

Comment: Such a rookie error, I did as you both said and it now returns all the records which exist in the database.